# How can I use Groovy to execute a shell command that has backticks?

Tags: bash, shell, groovy, backticks

I’m unable to use Groovy to execute a shell command that has backticks. A simplified example:

```
println "echo `date`".execute().text
```

I searched around and tried to figure out how to escape them somehow, but without luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What happens if you try:

```
println ["bash", "-c", "echo `date`"].execute().text
```

My guess would be that with

```
"echo `date`".execute()
```

java's `Runtime#exec(String)` would be used underneath, if you were calling `execute()` on a String. In which case, this simply tokenizes the string and executes the program `echo` with the argument

```
`date`
```

or

```
$(date)
```

but that's shell (bash) syntax, and must be executed via bash.

Comment: Almost, println had problems with this, but splitting it into two lines worked: `def process = ["bash", "-c", command].execute(); println process.text`